# How to control the <span> inside <div>

Tags: html

Please take a look of the weblink here ->

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhlao/rXHxT/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="ma">
    <div id="mi">
        <div id="r">
            <span class="b"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#ma{width:500px;height:500px;background:red;}
#mi{width:400px;height:350px;background:blue;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}
#r{width:200px;height:200px;background:green;float:right;margin:10px 10px 0 0;position:relative;}
#r .b{width:100px;height:100px;background:yellow;bottom:-100;position:absolute;}
```

Assume the yellow square is an image, and I want it to show at the bottom of the green box, with part of the image outside the green box.

I've test the css in the above link in my website, and the yellow box show just below the blue box. But at jsfiddle.net, it even ignore the bottom property.

Comment: just controll yellow boxes bottom parameter with pixels e.g: -50px

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the px:

```
#r .b{width:100px;height:100px;background:yellow;bottom:-100px;position:absolute;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm so careless

Comment: This happened to me on several occasions. Can take ages to track down if you keep overlooking it. Thank Creator for FireBug! Now, you can pick any answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot the "px" to the bottom property

currently :

```
bottom : 100;
```

must have

```
bottom : 100 px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do changes in your following css and corrected Fiddle is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/uk6G4/1/)**

```
#r .b{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:yellow;
position:absolute; 
bottom:-20px; 
left:-20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you expecting something like 
    [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/UXSree/QCHjH/)

```css
#ma{width:500px;height:500px;background:red;}
#mi{width:400px;height:350px;background:blue;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}
#r{width:200px;height:200px;background:green;float:right;margin:10px 10px 0      0;position:relative;}
#r .b{width:100px;height:100px;background:yellow;bottom:-50px;right:-10px;position:absolute;z-index:-1;}
```